# ASP.NET, jquery get hidden fields values on asp:button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two hidden fields which get latitude and longitude on a button click using jQuery. Below is the code working good, I want to calculate the distance using these lat and lng. For testing Im trying to show the hidden field value in textbox and label, you can see that in jQuery. However if I set the property as **OnClientClick="return true"** in button code I dont see anything working. If I set as **return false** I can see the values but not in label.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        $("#btn").on("click", function () {
            var address = $("#tbCity").val();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    //alert(latitude + ", " + longitude);
                }

                $('#latitude').val(lat);
                $('#longitude').val(lng);
                $('#txtBox1').val($('#latitude').val());   
                $('#txtBox2').val($('#longitude').val());
                $('#lbl1').val($('#latitude').val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

ASP.NET code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     Address: <asp:TextBox ID="tbCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>        
     <asp:HiddenField ID="latitude" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="longitude" runat="server" />
     <br /><br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return false"  OnClick="btn_Click"/>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Generated HTML code

```
    <form method="post" action="GetCoordinates.aspx" id="form2">
         <div class="aspNetHidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"   value="/wEPDwUKLTQyNTI1OTg4N2RkGXXMNhEfkB7Ie6CVb4YTwItExhof/IkHpdh6f26grxc=">
         </div>
        <div class="aspNetHidden">
             <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION"  value="/wEdAAeWsE0BRbQ0wjG1w60jqqdcq35qZMbaIVF3xrHN6flGNv+/yOgSqO/6irT+NtXuduQ93hcP/MBYTB//29SOqPZfAcmup7kkBHBfToLV39zc8Mj6eKFRARwXIj8IINCyLct0YEyduRVooG3ha/OFYKMXG9w1RtaOWHfqueLltflOGuLDyL1I+PDm4fhtuLq7nGM=">
        </div>
        Address: <input name="tbCity" type="text" id="Text1">        
                 <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="Hidden1" value="-34.92862119999999">
                 <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="Hidden2" value="138.5999594">       
                 <input name="txtBox1" type="text" id="Text2">
                 <input name="txtBox2" type="text" id="Text3">
                 <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Button" onclick="return false;" id="Submit1">        
        <span id="Span1">Label</span>
     </form>
```

Updated code

```
<form method="post" action="GetCoordinates.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEyMTQwNTA2MzFkZBAUxV0uM2MNtGYuUK81rFUmmAiaeLksG6QHsLB3zWtZ">
</div>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAci5mChXqDZFj3vgdOgA11rq35qZMbaIVF3xrHN6flGNv+/yOgSqO/6irT+NtXuduQ93hcP/MBYTB//29SOqPZfAcmup7kkBHBfToLV39zc8Mj6eKFRARwXIj8IINCyLct0YEyduRVooG3ha/OFYKMX/9MR/+s9E/Yu8cFwBQ5SCqt4ngV9Kdj9/OR/r/Q8mvQ=">
</div>
    Address: <input name="tbCity" type="text" id="tbCity">        
    <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude" value="-34.92862119999999">
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude" value="138.5999594">     
    <br><br>
    <input name="txtBox1" type="text" id="txtBox1">
    <input name="txtBox2" type="text" id="txtBox2">        
    <input name="btn" type="button" id="btn" value="showCode">
    <span id="lbl1">Label</span>
</form>
```

Updated .Net code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Address: <asp:TextBox ID="tbCity" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="latitude" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="longitude" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="button"   id="btn" runat="server"  value="showCode" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add your generated HTML code.

Comment: All your `ID` attributes became to `name`. Try to add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your controllers and check the generated HTML code and element's ID.

Comment: I dont see any difference but the tag id remain as txtbox1..

Comment: @NOX I can able to get the values to textbox using html button but not asp:button and label doesnt work

Comment: @VenkaYeluri Please paste your updated `.NET` and `GENERATED` HTML code with `ClientIDMode` attribute, then debugging would be easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T54Qz/1/)**

With `ClientIDMode="Static"` you've added to page controlls,
we're now sure the ID generated by ASP.NET is the same.

So now, your code works correctly, except your label.
As `<asp:Label />` is rendered as an `<span>` tag, so
you must use `.text()` method instead of `.val()`:

```
$('#lbl1').text($('#latitude').val());
```

Comment: Its working! If I use asp:button its still same. I need to connect to my DB and store these lat n lng on button click. Im using onclick="btn_Click" in my HTML button controller. Is this correct as I see no event is firing

Comment: @VenkaYeluri You can use **Ajax** for this reason, in your `click` event handler. Ofcourse, you must write a `service` or something like that in your project to handle the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you can remove both the `OnClientClick="return false"` and `OnClick="btn_Click"`. Your jquery code will handle the click event.

I also noticed your ids are different than the generated html. Try this updated code.

```
    $("#Submit1").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var address = $("#tbCity").val();
        var lat, lang;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lang = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                //alert(latitude + ", " + longitude);
            }

            $('#Hidden1').val(lat);
            $('#Hidden2').val(lang);
            $('#Text2').val(lat);   
            $('#Text3').val(lang);
            $('#Span1').val(lat);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I dont see any values either in textbox or label if I remove that

Comment: Hi.. with your recent edit, I can see that the ID's of your hiddenfields are different. It's Hidden1 and Hidden2. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have tried in either ways, it still exits. I have set clientIdMode="static" then the Html code remains same

Comment: I can able to get the values to textbox using html button but not asp:button and label doesnt work